# Polymorphic Link with React, Styled Components and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, polymorphism, styled-components

I'm trying to build a Link component that defaults as an a tag but will allow a user to pass React Router DOM or Next.JS Link components and remain strongly typed.

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm shocked that I haven't been able to find others with the same issue but maybe I'm just not searching for the right things.

Here is my code

```
export const NewLinkStyles = styled.a`
  align-items: center;
  color: ${({ theme }: { theme: Theme }) => theme.primary.step10};
`

export type CustomLinkProps<C extends React.ElementType = 'a'> = {
  as?: C;
  Icon?: IconType;
  selected?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
} & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<C>;

export type LinkProps<C extends React.ElementType> = React.PropsWithChildren<
  CustomLinkProps<C>
> &
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<C> &
  Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<C>, keyof CustomLinkProps<C>>;

export const NewLink = <C extends React.ElementType>({
  as,
  children,
  ...restProps
}: LinkProps<C>) => {
  return <StyledNewLink {...restProps}>{children}</StyledNewLink>;
};
```

And my expected results.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const TestComp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NewLink as={'a'} href="https://google.com"> // should alert if try to use to='/home'
        Hi
      </NewLink>
      <NewLink as={Link} to="https://google.com"> // should allert if you try to use href
        Hi
      </NewLink>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I feel like I should use one of the interfaces that come with styled components but wasn't having any luck. Thank you so much for your help! This has been driving me bonkers!

Comment: Here is a code sandbox that is a bit more simplified but still having issues with the as prop.
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-typescript-forked-f6x83v?file=/components/Link.tsx